# VS Code color coding for comments in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates, visual-studio-code

Can I write a custom rule to color code the comments in Django Templates?

files *.html
Example of the tags to trigger on

```
{% comment %}
Text in the comment.
{% endcomment %}
```

I don't think the Django Snippet plugins do this, but I could be wrong.

What I'd like is for that code to show as commented out based on my current theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the [plugin called `Django Template`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bibhasdn.django-html) and it highlights the comments:

[image]

Comment: As a side note... there's a bug in django-templates snippet vs. the code coloring.

When you add a comment via the snippet it looks like this:

{% comment "" %}
{%end comment %}


Note the double-quotes for you provide an optional note. But, if you do that... the color coding breaks. :-/

If anyone gets to a PR before me, go for it. ;-)

Comment: Interesting, @Patrick - It seems to be expected in their code. https://github.com/iambibhas/vscode-django-template/blob/master/snippets/django-snippets.json#L6

Comment: That's the shipper code. The syntax code does the highlighting (I think) and it does not have it. https://github.com/iambibhas/vscode-django-template/blob/master/syntaxes/django-html.json

Comment: true. well, I've added a PR suggesting a change https://github.com/iambibhas/vscode-django-template/pull/7/files

Comment: You rock! Thanks.